# Zeeman effect on a superposition state

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy

I am currently studying Magneto-optical trap(MOT). When a photon absorption takes place, there is a transition of an atom from an initial state to a final state (more accurately an electron in the atom goes to an excited state). We can consider the superposition of the two states as a new state with frequency $\Omega=\omega_2-\omega_1$. Because of the Zeeman effect energy levels on an atom split. We can have a normal or abnormal Zeeman effect, depending whether spin is taken or not in consideration. But my question is:

Does the superposed state also splits under the influence of an external magnetic field? In the case for a MOT, we have 2 resonance frequencies. I don't understand where do these come from and why are only 2.